# How to bind complex data models in SpringMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

The page is submitted via the asynchronous (ajax) form, and the data is very complex, as follows:

```
draw:1
columns[0][data]:id
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:productType
columns[1][name]:
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:city
columns[2][name]:
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
columns[3][data]:borrowPeriod
columns[3][name]:
columns[3][searchable]:true
columns[3][orderable]:true
columns[3][search][value]:
columns[3][search][regex]:false
columns[4][data]:interestType
columns[4][name]:
columns[4][searchable]:true
columns[4][orderable]:true
columns[4][search][value]:
columns[4][search][regex]:false
columns[5][data]:interestRange
columns[5][name]:
columns[5][searchable]:true
columns[5][orderable]:true
columns[5][search][value]:
columns[5][search][regex]:false
columns[6][data]:username
columns[6][name]:
columns[6][searchable]:true
columns[6][orderable]:true
columns[6][search][value]:
columns[6][search][regex]:false
columns[7][data]:birthday
columns[7][name]:
columns[7][searchable]:true
columns[7][orderable]:true
columns[7][search][value]:
columns[7][search][regex]:false
columns[8][data]:loanAmount
columns[8][name]:
columns[8][searchable]:true
columns[8][orderable]:true
columns[8][search][value]:
columns[8][search][regex]:false
columns[9][data]:phone
columns[9][name]:
columns[9][searchable]:true
columns[9][orderable]:true
columns[9][search][value]:
columns[9][search][regex]:false
columns[10][data]:sex
columns[10][name]:
columns[10][searchable]:true
columns[10][orderable]:true
columns[10][search][value]:
columns[10][search][regex]:false
columns[11][data]:extInfo
columns[11][name]:
columns[11][searchable]:true
columns[11][orderable]:true
columns[11][search][value]:
columns[11][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:asc
start:0
length:10
search[value]:
search[regex]:false
```

Background how to bind?I tried a lot of ways but did not succeed.

```
/**
 * @return 
 */
@PostMapping("xxx-application")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> loanApplication(
    @RequestParam int draw, @RequestParam(name = "length") int rows,
    @RequestParam int start, @RequestParam String[][] columns) {

    return data;
}
```

These attempts are unsuccessful, so I need everyone's help! `@RequestParam String[][] columns` `@RequestParam Map<String, Object> columns` `@RequestParam ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> columns`

Comment: Create an object... Spring will do the binding. The object has to have fields `start`, `length` and a collection for `order` and `columns` (probably a `List`) with nested objects that match that structure.

Comment: I am not very clear, can you help me write the example?